# "Notify authorities" Or "Notify the authorities"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if I have to use **'the'** before **'authorities'** in the following context?

> *If you suspect that something illegal is going on, you are supposed to notify (**the**) authorities right away.*

Could you also explain the logic of using it(**'the'**) or not in the context?

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=must+notify+the+authorities%2Cmust+notify+authorities&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that the article-less version has been gaining at least *some* traction over recent decades. But only in AmE, and even there it's still very much a minority usage (it's still virtually unknown in BrE without the article). But this is really just a matter of idiomatically established usages, not "rules", "logic", or "principles" of semantics or syntax.

Comment: Where the noun is singular, the article is optional, e.g. "I like movies," or "I like the movies." As mentioned, British and American English may differ, as in, "He went to hospital," UK usage, vs. the U.S. "He went to the hospital."